# Postgres alternatives for Oracle DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK and DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, amazon-aurora, ora2pg

What are the equal/closest alternatives in Postgres for Oracle `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK` and `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GET DIAGNOSTICS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CALL-STACK) or `GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS` statement and read a `PG_CONTEXT` field.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION outer_func() RETURNS integer AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN inner_func();
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inner_func() RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
  stack text;
BEGIN
  GET DIAGNOSTICS stack = PG_CONTEXT;
  RAISE NOTICE E'--- Call Stack ---\n%', stack;
  RETURN 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT outer_func();

NOTICE:  --- Call Stack ---
PL/pgSQL function inner_func() line 5 at GET DIAGNOSTICS
PL/pgSQL function outer_func() line 3 at RETURN
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function outer_func() line 3 at RETURN
outer_func
------------
        1
(1 row)
```

Comment: Can I use the same for `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK` as well?

Comment: Postgres itself has not `DBMS_UTILITY` package. You can try to install `orafce` extension, and that extension has emulation of this package.